# How to find a range in Excel where the condition can be met by one of several values?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How can I find and sum all cells in column BR where... 
BO=TOKYO and BP=JP and BQ= 1312 or 1401 or 1402.

. . . BO . . .BP. . . BQ . . . BR

---

TOKYO . . JP . . 1309 . . 1,927

TOKYO . . JP . . 1310 . . 1,633

TOKYO . . JP . . 1311 . . 2,553

TOKYO . . JP . . 1312 . . 2,878

TOKYO . . JP . . 1401 . . 1,581

TOKYO . . JP . . 1402 . . 2,050

Grateful for help, this has already taken too much of my time =(

Comment: vlookup with match and sumifs, but they all just give me the cell where the one condition is met, I cant ask for all the cells where one or another condition is met.

Comment: Have you tried using a filter?

Comment: No, I cant use a filter on the data. The selection is to be made on a dashboard in another sheet and the formula needs to be dynamic.

Comment: it is doable, please give us a proper example of what you what to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You can add 3 sumifs:

```
=SUMIFS(BR:BR,BO:BO,"TOKYO",BP:BP,"JP",BQ:BQ,1312)+SUMIFS(BR:BR,BO:BO,"TOKYO",BP:BP,"JP",BQ:BQ,1401)+SUMIFS(BR:BR,BO:BO,"TOKYO",BP:BP,"JP",BQ:BQ,1402)
```

There may be an array formula that would be shorter but I suck at array formulas.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I could, but the formula would not be dynamic enough. 1312 is year 13 month 12 and that date should be changed from the dashboard. The dream would be if I on the dashboard could choose a date like 1312 and then set number of months to include in the range after that. The selection "1312" and "3" would make the formula return the cells for 1312, 1401 and 1402. Mabye Im just dreamin =(

Comment: it is doable, please give us a proper example of what you what to achieve.